# Racket scheme read write png files

Tags: scheme, png, racket

In Racket scheme are there any libraries that allow you to read in a png, alter the image and write it back to disk?  Failing png any other common image formats.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is support for PNGs.  You can load them as a [bitmap](http://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/bitmap_.html) and then write them out with the `save-file` method.

Answer (score 1):

There's at least built-in support for GIF: http://docs.racket-lang.org/file/gif.html